# What exactly "manage trust" in CA is doing? (on-premise)

Tags: security, ssl

I have experience on setting up SP2010, 2013 and 2016. In order to install SSL cert and to support https to browse SharePoint, beside install the cert in IIS, usually we need to import the certificate in CA > Security > Manage Trust.

However, I have tested even I do not import the cert to Manage Trust, everything is working fine. All users can login SharePoint with https://xxx and none of the service/feature have issue. The step to import cert seems to be useless.

Could you please clarify what "manage trust" is actually doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage trust is only needed if  you like to consume/connect two different/several SharePoint farms to be able to communicate or share some services between them. If you only have one farm, you don't need to bother with those settings in CA.

From Microsoft's official documentation:

> In SharePoint Server, a farm can connect to and consume a service
>   application that is published on another SharePoint Server farm. For
>   this to occur, the farms must exchange trust certificates.
>
> Both farms must participate in this exchange for service application
>   sharing to work.

[Exchange trust certificates between farms in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/exchange-trust-certificates-between-farms)

[Share service applications across farms in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/share-service-applications-across-farms)

Comment: Is it required to connect to external non-SharePoint services? e.g. SSRS (native mode), external ASP.NET program.

Comment: As with everything - it depends on what you are trying to achieve. BCS service exists for a reason, other than that - integrating/communicating with a external system depends on so many other things that it's hard to give an answer that applies to any case. To the specific setting of managing trust in SP? No.